# VbScript to strip space of string?

Tags: string, vbscript, strip, wsh

Say I have a string that = Grilled Cheese

How would I echo the string without the space between Grilled Cheese with out changing the string?

Also if I had a string that variables but will always have a space, like a full name. I can show the first letter of the string:

```
WScript.Echo Left(strUserName, 1) will echo for example G
```

but how could I show the name after the space (= Cheese).  Keep in mind the name after the space may change like "Cheesy" for example

`WScript.Echo Mid(strUserName,null)` does not work

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29) function can be used to remove characters from a string. If you just echo the return value without assigning it back to the variable, the original string will remain unchanged:

```
>>> str = "Grilled Cheese"
>>> WScript.Echo Replace(str, " ", "")
GrilledCheese
>>> WScript.Echo str
Grilled Cheese
```

Another option would be the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29) and [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29) functions:

```
>>> str = "Grilled Cheese"
>>> WScript.Echo Join(Split(str, " "), "")
GrilledCheese
>>> WScript.Echo str
Grilled Cheese
```

`Split` will also allow you to echo just particular tokens from the original string:

```
>>> str = "Grilled Cheese"
>>> WScript.Echo Split(str, " ")(1)
Cheese
```